# How can I stop server after a particular uptime?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04

I need to stop server running at aws within 750 hours. Is there anyway i can automate it shutdown process within that time limit ?

Comment: Do you want to stop only the apache service or to shutdown the system completely?

Comment: I need to stop the system completely.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple bash script to do this job (save this to a file with .sh extension):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

reboot=$((750*3600))
uptime=$(awk -F. '{print $1}' /proc/uptime)

if [ $uptime -ge $reboot ]; then
  shutdown -h
fi
```

Let me explain:

```bsh
reboot=$((750*3600))
```

We get the representation of 750 hours in seconds

```bsh
uptime=$(awk -F. '{print $1}' /proc/uptime)
```

This is the system uptime in seconds

After you saved the file give it executable permissions:

```
chmod +x name-of-your-file.sh
```

You can set a cron job to execute this script every hour:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Then paste this:

```
0 * * * *  /path/to/your/script.sh
```

Comment: Since you're using bash anyway, you could use shell arithmetic instead of `[`: `if (( reboot > uptime )); then ...`